# Adjusting gamma in VirtualBox guest (debian)

Tags: debian, virtualbox

Using Kgamma5 in plasma5, I attempted to adjust the gamma of my debian guest OS inside virtualbox. My white levels seem too bright. No effect. I looked around, and while I found no specific info about gamma, I learned the virtual graphics driver in virtual box (and other virtualizers?) don't support things like color management (and therefore gamma, I assume).

Is there any hope for reducing the gamma in my guest os?